# Excel VBA Code performance is Extremely Slow

Tags: excel, vba

I have wrote a code which is working like Turtle walks. I have added Application Functions to make it faster but code has decided that he has to work slowly.

Any expert help will be appreciated.

```
Dim LastRowColumnA As Long
Dim i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
LastRowColumnA = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 11 To LastRowColumnA
If Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
Cells(i, 7) = Evaluate("=INDEX(Table1!$A$1:$DP$27,MATCH($G$9&$E$4,Table1!$E:$E&Table1!$F:$F,0),MATCH(A" & i & ",Table1!$6:$6,0))")
Cells(i, 8) = Evaluate("=INDEX(Table1!$A$1:$DP$27,MATCH($H$9&$E$4,Table1!$E:$E&Table1!$F:$F,0),MATCH(A" & i & ",Table1!$6:$6,0))")
Cells(i, 9) = Evaluate("=INDEX(Table1!$A$1:$DP$27,MATCH($I$9&$E$4,Table1!$E:$E&Table1!$F:$F,0),MATCH(A" & i & ",Table1!$6:$6,0))")
Cells(i, 10) = Evaluate("=INDEX(Table1!$A$1:$DP$27,MATCH($J$9&$E$4,Table1!$E:$E&Table1!$F:$F,0),MATCH(A" & i & ",Table1!$6:$6,0))")
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
Next
```

second approach.

```
Dim LastRowColumnA As Long
LastRowColumnA = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

Sheet1.Range("G10").FormulaArray = _
"=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1!R1C1:R27C120,MATCH(R9C7&R4C5,Table1!C5&Table1!C6,0),MATCH(RC[-6],Table1!R6,0)), """")"
Sheet1.Range("G10").AutoFill Destination:=Sheet1.Range("G10:G" & LastRowColumnA), Type:=xlFillDefault

Sheet1.Range("H10").FormulaArray = _
"=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1!R1C1:R27C120,MATCH(R9C8&R4C5,Table1!C5&Table1!C6,0),MATCH(RC[-7],Table1!R6,0)), """")"
Sheet1.Range("H10").AutoFill Destination:=Sheet1.Range("H10:H" & LastRowColumnA), Type:=xlFillDefault

Sheet1.Range("I10").FormulaArray = _
"=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1!R1C1:R27C120,MATCH(R9C9&R4C5,Table1!C5&Table1!C6,0),MATCH(RC[-8],Table1!R6,0)), """")"
Sheet1.Range("I10").AutoFill Destination:=Sheet1.Range("I10:I" & LastRowColumnA), Type:=xlFillDefault

Sheet1.Range("J10").FormulaArray = _
"=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1!R1C1:R27C120,MATCH(R9C9&R4C5,Table1!C5&Table1!C6,0),MATCH(RC[-9],Table1!R6,0)), """")"
Sheet1.Range("J10").AutoFill Destination:=Sheet1.Range("J10:J" & LastRowColumnA), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Formulas of First Cells which has been converted to code.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1!$A$1:$DP$27,MATCH($G$9&$E$4,Table1!$E:$E&Table1!$F:$F,0),MATCH(A10,Table1!$6:$6,0)), "")

=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1!$A$1:$DP$27,MATCH($H$9&$E$4,Table1!$E:$E&Table1!$F:$F,0),MATCH(A10,Table1!$6:$6,0)), "")

=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1!$A$1:$DP$27,MATCH($I$9&$E$4,Table1!$E:$E&Table1!$F:$F,0),MATCH(A10,Table1!$6:$6,0)), "")

=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1!$A$1:$DP$27,MATCH($J$9&$E$4,Table1!$E:$E&Table1!$F:$F,0),MATCH(A10,Table1!$6:$6,0)), "")
```

Comment: `Application.Calculation` affects the formulas on the sheet. You are not triggering formulas on a sheet, you are calculating them yourself with `Evaluate`, so `Application.Calculation` has no effect. If you wanted to put the formula in the cells instead of the result, then use `.Formula` and remove `Evaluate`. The formula is also the same for all cells, so you can remove the loop.

Comment: The answer to these question are almost always to use variant arrays to capture the used ranges and iterate those, this question is no different.  At least you should limit the full column references to just the data set.  You are doing over 8 million calculations every loop.  That is going to be slow.

Comment: @GSerg the formula is not the same, see the last MATCH, it refers to a different cell.

Comment: @ScottCraner The last `MATCH` refers to the cell from the same row in which the formula is located. That is the same formula, even though it does not look that way in the A1 notation (but it does in the R1C1 notation).

Comment: fair point @GSerg but I doubt it will be any quicker putting the formula in the cells and then calculating and then copy pasting the values. As the array formula will still need to do over 8 million calculations per row.

Comment: It looks like you could do the first match in each Evaluate once and set it to a variable.  The second match only needs to be evaluated once per loop.  That should cut out repetitive calculations.

Comment: I did it with different way but it is also a slower one. Let me update the second one

Comment: `Table1!$E:$E&Table1!$F:$F` in your formula should be `Table1!$E$1:$E$27&Table1!$F$1:$F$27`  Just doing that will make it much quicker , but as @auxary stated, if you find the row using 4 evaluates before the loop, like: `ActiveSheet.Evaluate("MATCH($G$9&$E$4,Table1!$E$1:$E$27&Table1!$F$1:$F$27,0)")` then inside the loop you only need to find the correct column: `Application.Match(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i),Worksheets("Table1").Range("6:6"),0)` into a variable then it is a simple `ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 7) = Worksheets("Table1").Cells(rowFromEvaluate, ColumnFromApplicationMatch)`

Comment: I got your point let me try this thing. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as per my comment:

Find the rows outside the loop as they will all be the same, then just find the column in the loop.  It will cut down on the number of calc.

```
Dim LastRowColumnA As Long
Dim i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

With Sheet1
    LastRowColumnA = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim gRow As Variant
    gRow = .Evaluate("MATCH($G$9&$E$4,Table1!$E1:$E27&Table1!$F1:$F27,0)")
    
    Dim hRow As Variant
    hRow = .Evaluate("MATCH($H$9&$E$4,Table1!$E1:$E27&Table1!$F1:$F27,0)")
    
    Dim iRow As Variant
    iRow = .Evaluate("MATCH($I$9&$E$4,Table1!$E1:$E27&Table1!$F1:$F27,0)")
    
    Dim jRow As Variant
    jRow = .Evaluate("MATCH($J$9&$E$4,Table1!$E1:$E27&Table1!$F1:$F27,0)")
    
    For i = 11 To LastRowColumnA
        If Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" And Not IsError(gRow) And Not IsError(hRow) And Not IsError(iRow) And Not IsError(jRow) Then
            Dim clm As Variant
            clm = Application.Match(.Range("A" & i), Worksheets("Table1").Range("6:6"), 0)
            If Not IsError(clm) Then
                .Cells(i, 7) = Worksheets("Table1").Cells(gRow, clm)
                .Cells(i, 8) = Worksheets("Table1").Cells(hRow, clm)
                .Cells(i, 9) = Worksheets("Table1").Cells(iRow, clm)
                .Cells(i, 10) = Worksheets("Table1").Cells(jRow, clm)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End With

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

If that is still too slow then one will need to use variant arrays and skip looping the ranges as this is slow.

Comment: It is faster one thank you very much. If i spend even whole night and day could not have been made a single line of this code. @Scott Craner Thank you again.